# TensorFlow Model Syntax

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am new to Neural Networks and Tensorflow

Usually, when we build a neural network model in TensorFlow we define it in the following way:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
```

I recently came up with a code using transfer learning and it defined the model in the following way:

```
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Here `last_output` is the output of the transfer learning model.

Can anyone explain how this is different from the Sequential Method? also, why is the output of the previous layer given in parenthesis at the end of the new layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the ways you have described are correct. Let us take a look at it step by step.

1. First model is using the `Sequential` API.The declaration of this API is as follows.

   tf.keras.Sequential(
   layers=None, name=None
   )

The API takes `layers` argument as a list of `layers` to add to the model.

Hence, the example you showed.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu')])
```

Here the sequential API stacks each layer on top of another and connects them. This API manages on it's own the output of the previous layers is the input to the next layer. It provides us with the convinience.

2.Approach is to create the model using `Functional` API. You can think of it as calling a layer as a function. The only thing you will have to do extra is to provide a previous layer as the input to the next layer. As Functional API doen't use something similar to List so the only way the API will know from which layer does the input come is to actually provide the previous layer as an argument.

So taking your example.

```
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

The functional API will know that the layer `Flatten` needs to be connected to `last_output` layer. Then the next dense layer will be connected to the `Flatten` layer as `x` is passed as an argument to it. I think you get the idea here.

There is also one more way to create Model is by subclassing the `Model` class.
You can look at the `Functional` API and the subclassing `Model` class [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model).

Comment: could you also explain which one is a better way to go about? as most transfer learning programs use the functional API and the rest are using the Sequential API and is there any difference between the two?

Comment: So basically there is nothing right or wrong here. And there is no performance advantage in either of them. The only difference is that engineers prefer using the Functional API as it provides the functional way of writing the code and I think it also makes it intuitive in doing transfer learning. So you are right the functional API is used more often in transfer learning problems. But at the end, it is also up to you and your coding style.